# Magento 2 : Add comment field in checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout-page, addfield

I want to add the Delivery Comment field in the checkout page like this.
[image]

How can I do that?
Any help? Thank in advance.

Comment: This might help https://github.com/boldcommerce/magento2-ordercomments

Comment: Thank you for suggesting .how can I have it below the shipping method, do you have any idea?

Comment: No, this would appear after payment, I have used this module, it's good, but it's appear after payment

Comment: I know, but my customers request it appears after the shipping method.

Comment: I think this may be helps you https://github.com/sohelrana09/magento2-module-delivery-date/tree/master/SR/DeliveryDate

Comment: @divyasekar Thank you, It's helpful

Comment: sounds good. happy coding :) @MichaelHa

Answer (score -2):

I was also searching for this and I went to [**THIS WEBSITE**](https://www.mageplaza.com/review/order-comment/), Please take a look at this, also I'll recommend you to use **Ulmod** extension you can also customize as per you need.